# how to set border arround textview in android

Tags: android

```
if (chat.getSenderID().equals(prefs.getString("Member_id", ""))) {
            root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#07000000"));
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#636363"));
            root.setPadding(60, 0, 0, 0);
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ad9a"));
            tv.setBackgroundResource(anim.mercy1);
}
else
{
    root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#07000000"));
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

            tv.setBackgroundResource(anim.mercy2);

            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            root.setPadding(0, 0, 60, 0);
}
```

mercy1:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#00ad9a" />
   <stroke android:width="1dip"  android:color="#cccccc"/>
</shape>
```

mercy2:

```
android:shape="rectangle" >
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
   <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#cccccc"/>
</shape>
```

I am calling set background resource using given code i want actually border only top ,bottom ,right left using that code am able to set border but i want hide left border when layout will odd when layout will even then i want hide border only right means in odd i want to set left=0 top=1 bottom=2 right=0 while in even left=1 top=1 bottom=2 right=1 :

look my current Screen  using given code :[image]

Desire Screen :

[image]

Comment: Show the XML containing that TextView

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/naRkvG3KJJuuKfJs9Ri8aG  but i  have to change it programtically

Comment: Which one of these is a TextView we're talking about?

Comment: android:id="@+id/text"

Comment: I made something similar using a ListView, I made a pojo which returned user1 and user2, and in adapter while setting the text, I checked the value, if user1, I set it to parentRight otherwise left.

Comment: can send u code of adapter class

Answer (score 1):

You can set padding to 0dp for hide only right or left border.

**borderline.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#3090C7" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a container view (such as a FrameLayout) and set its background to your border colour, and then add padding to it.  Add your view to the container view as a child.  You'll also need to set your actual view's background colour to something appropriate. The padded area will show the border colour.  You can then control which sides show by setting paddingLeft, paddingTop, etc. appropriately.

Comment: but see my current screen i have to remove only  right and left color what i will change in XMl

Answer (score 0):

You should use Android Nine Patches to generate those chat bubbles. With nine patches its easy to add shadows and borders as well and its more efficient.

You can then use color filters to change the color of the bubbles to any color you want at runtime.